# Java Regex Negate certain word

Tags: java, regex

I need some help creating a regular expression.
I need to get all the words between the first keyword and the last keyword.

Assume the first keyword is `All` and the last keyword is `At`.

Sample Input:

> All abc abcd abcccc abdd At

The output must be:

> abc abcd abccc abdd

This is my current regex right now:

```
(\\s*All (\\w|\\s)+( At))
```

My problem is that if ever the input is like this:

> All abc abc abc abc abc At At

The output is:

> abc abc abc abc abc At

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try non-greedy matching for the words in the middle:

```
(\s*All (\w|\s)+?( At))
```

Note the added `?` sign. This should tell regex engine to return the shortest match for the `(\w|\s)+` part, hopefully yielding the result you need.

Answer (score 0):

Shorten your String before:

```
String toSearchFor = source.substring (source.indexOf ("All"), source.indexOf ("At")+"At".length);
```

However, I'm not sure what to do with

```
"At At All abc At All def All ghi At jkl At At All"
```